# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (consume) on node type (GamesIAPOrder)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-payments

I'm trying implement [Payments Lite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/payments_lite).

Purchase request works without any issues.

Same for purchases list. It returns:

```
[
  {
    "purchase_token": "###",
    "product_id": "###",
    "app_id": "###",
    "purchase_time": ###,
    "payment_id": "######",
    "consumed": false,
    "signed_request": "###",
    "payment_action_type": "charge"
  }
]
```

But if I try to consume this purchase using `purchase_token` the request returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (consume) on node type (GamesIAPOrder)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "CPjKLsTkf/G
"
  }
}
```

I'm using this code:

```
FB.API("/" + purchaseToken + "/consume", HttpMethod.GET, OnConsume, new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"access_token", accessToken}
});
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the code you use for calling the api

Comment: Without you providing some code it is imposible to solve this

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg I've updated the question

Comment: Great. Isnt it supposed to be HttpMethod.POST instead of GET?

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg ohh...Exactly!

Comment: Great. If that solves it ill write a quick answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to consume a `purchase_token` should be using `HttpMethod.POST` instead of `HttpMethod.GET`

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/payments_lite#consuming